# Simple max function bothering me

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

Simple query bothering me.  I can't seem to get it right and I know it's so simple:

```
Select username
From hsi.wftransactionlog
where logdate = (Select max(logdate) From hsi.wftransactionlog)
```

I want to return the username with the highest logdate.

I am looking for 1 row per username. The one with the max date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am looking for 1 row per username. The one with the max date.

Then probably you want to do a `group by` like

```
Select t1.*
From hsi.wftransactionlog t1
join (Select username, max(logdate) as maxlogdate
From hsi.wftransactionlog
group by username) xxx 
on t1.username = xxx.username and t1.logdate = xxx.maxlogdate;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for one row, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
Select username
From hsi.wftransactionlog
order by logdate desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  This does not return ties, whereas your version does.

Comment: I am looking for 1 row per username.  The one with the max date.

Comment: "I want to return the username with the highest logdate."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the logtes are unique, it's easier to just sort the query and take the top row:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     hsi.wftransactionlog
ORDER BY logdate DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: I am looking for 1 row per username.  The one with the max date.